# I dont know how to update android wia twrp

Tags: ota-update, twrp

I root my LG G3 month ago. I also installed TWRP recovery.

Today an Android update comes to my phone. I download the update, my phone restarts and shows TWRP. So I reboot my phone again – but again it shows TWRP!

Now I dont know what to do. Please help me to get my Android system running again. Currently, regardless of what I try, it always boots to TWRP.

Comment: Please explain the steps you tried clearly so that the users can help you

Answer (score 1):

Its because you changed the stock recovery to twrp. OTA update requires stock recovery.

Try the below steps :

1. Download the [file](http://downloads.codefi.re/autoprime/LG/LG_G3/flash2/LG_G3_Flash2FixStuckRecovery.zip)
2. Connect your phone to pc and select the mount option in twrp
3. Copy the downloaded file to the phone
4. Flash the zip using twrp

Comment: thanks for you cooperation but i dont now what to do ,,,,

Comment: on my phone screen shows just twrp so now what steps should i take please help again just twrp shows on my screen I reboot phone but nothing again shows twrp, what steps should i take

Comment: @fatos You should run those commands from the PC via console. You'll need to download Android SDK (Hint, look for Android Mini SDK in Google. ADB tool is there.)